# How to make single Aggregate result with (multiple) recorded HTTP Request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing

I have recorded few actions using JMeter and extracted multiple HTTP Request to test. Here, while running the test with single user I can get multiple results WRT my HTTP Request. Is there any possible to extract single result for multiple HTTP Request?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Dmitri T Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Listener of [Generate Summary Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Generate_Summary_Results)

run in non GUI mode and it will display only summary

for example:

Generate Summary Results =      7 in 00:00:02 =    4.2/s Avg:   222 Min:     2 M
ax:   757 Err:     0 (0.00%)

Comment: above things executed successfully (GUI Mode), on the 1st time. But again it executing multiple results only. can you help on this ?

Comment: it should be used in non GUI mode

Comment: also notice there's a time limit in jmeter.properties (interval between summaries (in seconds) default 30 seconds)
#summariser.interval=30

Comment: I cannot extract any results using Generate Summary results, for your convenience I have attached screen shot of my test result. I tried using both GUI & Non-GUI mode.

Comment: Where is the screenshot for non gui?

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


[![enter image description here][3]][3]


[![enter image description here][4]][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLvaa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LgDs.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLQDX.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9LUY.png

Comment: Please verify the above screenshots for test reports executed by using both GUI and non GUI mode